# Erro na aplicação ao mudar para enable 32-bits = True no IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

Uso o CobrebemX na minha aplicação web asp.net para imprimir boletos. Trocamos de servidor e agora quando eu habilito a opção `enable 32-bits = True` para o "Application pool" da referida aplicação acontece o seguinte erro:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Module    IIS Web Core Notification   Unknown Handler Not yet determined
>   Error Code    0x80070032 Config Error The configuration section
>   'connectionStrings' cannot be read because it is missing a section
>   declaration Config
>   File  \?\C:\inetpub\xxxx-xxxxx\Painel-Geral\web.config
>
> Requested URL http://www.xxxxxxxx.com.br:80/portal/Default.aspx
>   Physical Path  Logon Method   Not yet determined Logon User   Not yet
>   determined
>
> Config Source
>       3: 
>       4:   
>       5:

E isso não ocorre quando deixo a opção de 32-bits desabilitada. Alguém sabe como resolver isso, por favor?

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e colocar o conteúdo do seu arquivo `Web.config`?

Answer (score -1):

@Romulo_Reis, Primeiro verifique se você está utilizando Default AppPool e se ele tem permissão para acessar o local onde está a aplicação.

Neste [Link](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) tem mais informações que pode te ajudar.